# WPF xaml Binding (multiple values)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a button that is enabled only when an item is selected in one of my list controls:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">                             
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=ganttChartTaskListView}" Value="-1">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have to perform somewhat similar binding, however, in this new case I want to only have the button enabled when the SelectedIndex >= 1   (!= -1 && != 0)

How would I go about doing this in xaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an IValueConverter that returns True/False based on your condition. And change your Trigger to following:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=ganttChartTaskListView, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Well, generally, I have not found a single converter/library that satisfies all my needs. I usually end up creating my own converters. But, you may want to look into this one : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ScriptValueConverter.aspx?msg=2740680